# How to run multiple instance from a tcl script

Tags: multithreading, tcl, fork

I have a tcl script.
In that i created 3 telnet session to the server. But, i wanted to run set of commands to all telnet simultaneously and continuously. What is the best way to achieve it.

```
For Ex: For 1st Telent session : i run "show ospf" 
        For 2nd Telent session : i run "show interfaces"
        For 3rd Telent session : i run "show eigrp"
```

I execute the above commands simultaneously and continuously. Till the specified count.

Comment: How are you doing the telnet sessions?

Comment: Using TCL-expect spawn. And i hold the spawn_id in a variable called T1, T2, T3

Comment: What do you mean by "continuously"? Please show the code you currently have.

Comment: Continuously means for a range of time like. All three session execute send the command to same device for 15 minutes or 1k time.

Comment: May be this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950548/running-multiple-instances-of-one-tcl-script . Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

This is some code we used to use long time ago.

```
set commands [ list ]
lappend commands "no ip prefix-list DDOS permit $c_targetip/24"    
lappend commands "ip prefix-list DDOS seq $data permit $c_targetip/24"

lappend commands "router bgp"
lappend commands "network $c_targetip/24"
lappend commands "exit"

lappend allconnections "br2.sjc1"
lappend allconnections "br3.lax3"
lappend allconnections "br6.lax10"
lappend allconnections "br7.lax10"

# spawn all connections
foreach conn $allconnections {

    spawn telnet $conn
    lappend spawn_id_list $spawn_id

  }

  # run expect script for all connections individually
  foreach id $spawn_id_list {

    # this is important - for unknown (to me) reasons
    set spawn_id $id
    set timeout 30

    expect_after {
      timeout { catch { close }; wait; return 2 }
      eof { catch { close }; wait; return 1 }
    }

    expect {
      "Username: " {
        send "$user\r"
        exp_continue
      }
      "Password: " {
        send "$password\r"
        exp_continue
      }
      "#" {
        send "configure terminal\r" 
      }
    }

    expect "(config)#" 
    foreach command $commands {  
      send "$command\r"
      expect ")#"
    }

    send "exit\r"
    expect "#"
    send "exit\r"
    expect ">"
    send "exit\r"
    expect "closed"

    exp_close
    exp_wait

  }




  return 0;
}
```

`